# regex storing matches in wrong capture group

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a python regex with optional capture group. My regex works for most case but fails to put the matches in the right group in one of the test case.

I want to match and capture the following cases:

1. namespace::tool_name::1.0.1
2. namespace::tool_name
3. tool_name::1.0.1
4. tool_name

Here is the regex I have so far:

```
(?:(?P<namespace>^[^:]+)::)?(?P<name>[^:]*)(?:::(?P<version>[0-9\.]+))?
```

This regex works fine for all my 4 test cases but the problem I have is in case 3, the tool_name is capture in the namespace group and the 1.0.1 is captured in the name group. I would like them to be captured in the right groups, name and version respectively

Thanks

Comment: Just move the `^` out of the `namespace` group and put it at the beginning of your pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may make tool_name regex part obligatory by replacing `*` with `+` (it looks like it always is present) and restrict this pattern from matching three dot-separated digit chunks with a negative lookahead:

```
^(?:(?P<namespace>[^:]+)::)?(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){2})(?P<name>[^:]+)(?:::(?P<version>\d+(?:\.\d+){2}))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fopVtC/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?P<namespace>[^:]+)::)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any 1+ chars other than `:` into Group "namespace" and then just matches `::`
- `(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){2})` - a negative lookahead that does not allow `digits.digits.digits` pattern to appear right after the current position
- `(?P<name>[^:]+)` - Group "name": any 1 or more chars other than `:`
- `(?:::(?P<version>\d+(?:\.\d+){2}))?` - an optional  non-capturing group matching `::` and then Group "version" captures 1+ digits and 2 repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits.